# What is the correct way to handle collections of model objects in Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I am looking for some assistance or guidance on the best way to handle collections of objects in Wicket that won't have a devastating impact on session size.  Obviously wrapping an object with any of Wicket's IModel classes is ideal, but what is the best way to do that when working with a collection of objects (e.g. a collection of search results).

I have had success using LoadableDetachableModel when working with an individual object, but I appear to be getting a java.io.NotSerializableException intermittently when shutting down Tomcat.  Initially, I thought I was safe but the exception being thrown suggests otherwise.

This is the code (edited for brevity):

```
public class CandidateSearch extends BasicPage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private CandidateService service = new CandidateService();

public CandidateSearch() {
    ListView<Candidate> listView = new ListView<Candidate>("candidates", service.search()){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Candidate> item) {
            Candidate candidate = (Candidate) item.getModelObject();

            PageParameters pars = new PageParameters();
            pars.add("id", candidate.getId());
            Link<String> candidateLink = new BookmarkablePageLink<String>("candidateLink", CandidateDetails.class, pars);

            candidateLink.add(new Label("candidateId", "ID-" + new Long(candidate.getId()).toString()));

            item.add(candidateLink);
            item.add(new Label("name", candidate.getFirstName() + " " + candidate.getLastName()));
            item.add(new Label("location", candidate.getCity() + ", " + candidate.getState()));
        }

    };

    add(listView);

}
```

}

NOTE: service.search returns an java.util.List typed as Candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct the `ListView` like that, your `Candidate` objects will not be detachable...that's why you're getting the `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

I'm not sure if this is best practices or not, but my strategy is to convert the list of objects into a `LoadableDetachableModel` of a List.  I have a utility method like this:

```
public static <T> IModel<? extends List<T>> convertToListViewModel(List<T> objects) {

    final Class<? extends List> listClass = objects.getClass();

    // NOTE: you will need to implement the toLoadableDetachableModels method
    List<IModel<T>> asModels = toLoadableDetachableModels(objects);

    return new LoadableDetachableModel<List<T>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<T> load() {
            List<T> results = ClassUtils.newInstance(listClass);
            for(IModel<T> model : asModels) {
                results.add(model.getObject());
            }
            return results;
        }
    };
}
```

You could use this method to wrap the results of `service.search()`, and then not only should you should be rid of that error, but your objects will require much less session storage space.

Comment: This is excellent and hugely helpful.  Thank you so much to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

The process suggested by stevevis of converting your list to a `[LoadableDetachableModel][1]` is reasonable if you want to stick with something close to your current basic architecture.

A bigger change that would work as well and for some purposes maybe better would be to switch to using a [`DataView`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/repeater/data/DataView.html), so that the data shown comes from an implementation of [`IDataProvider`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/repeater/data/IDataProvider.html) as needed and is not held as you are doing in a `List` at all.

Good example code for these and other repeaters can be found at [the wicket examples site](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/).